# Trouble appending values to an array in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create an array that has values 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03... all the way up to 1.0.

Here is my input:

```
x=0
h=0.01
n=100
xArray=[x]

for i in (0,n):
    x += h
    xArray.append(x)
print, xArray
```

Here is my output:

[0, 0.01, 0.02]

I'm very confused why it's only adding two elements to the array.  How do I fix this?

Comment: You need the `range` function.

Comment: `xArray = [y * h for y in range(n + 1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntactical errors in your program.

The code should be like this

```
x=0
h=0.01
n=100
xArray=[x]

for i in range(0,n):
    x += h
    xArray.append(x)
print(xArray)
```

As you can see the for loop and print function are erroneous in your code.

Comment: I don't have any problem receiving an output from the print function with the way I originallly typed it.  The only difference is it also says (<function print>) in the output.  I am using Jupyter Notebook in a Python 3 Kernel.  Is there more than one correct way to call the print function?